# Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\Damien\'C:\Users\Damien\AppData\Roaming\npm''

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

I'm trying to start a react project so i downloaded Node and i tried to use the npm command and i get this error. I have tried changing all the Environment variables and they are all fine too.[Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zE1S.png)

Node is in my path variables and that's working fine too. I can do `nvm -v` and it returns the latest version. Anyone have any advice or guidence

> ```
> C:\Users\Damien>npm install -g create-react-app
> CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\Damien\'C:\Users\Damien\AppData\Roaming\npm'
> ```

Comment: use this `npx create-react-app myFolderName`

Comment: If i use that i get this > spawn C:\Windows\System32\; ENOENT

Comment: Install linux in your windows machine. Search linux on windows.

Comment: how does that solve my problem??